# What's the appriopriate behavior for this "SEE ALL" button? Opening modal window or moving to another tab?

Tags: mobile, user-expectation, search, material-design, tab

[image: Modal or different tab?]

Hello.

I'm designing b2b mobile app.

My main tab, "Overview" consists of sections:

- recently bought items
- some recommended products
- customer's vouchers
- some statistics

Those sections are in-a-nutshell representations of different tabs. (e.g. Clicking "See all" button in "Recent purchases" section moves you to "Purchases history" tab)

Which behavior of "SEE ALL" button is more appriopriate? I see problems with both solutions:

Option A) Button "SEE ALL" near "Recent purchases" indicates that you will see all of the RECENT purchases. Also search button's behavior in option A is unclear.

Option B) Problem: modal window would double the content that we can already access from the tab view. Problem with search button remains when the user visits the tab.

Comment: I do not see a problem with option B. I think the tabs should stay constant (so not A) and the overview already implies that you are viewing a ‘selection of’. Also, I think it is what most apps with this kind of overview do.

Comment: @gerstemout but don't you think doubling the content (on modal window and on tab) is a problem? Perhaps I should just remove all the tabs?

Comment: I don’t see doubled content. The tab from option A is not present in option B. And the overview hardly counts (those are just some examples of recent purchases, not an actually useful list).

Answer (score 1):

The best option is option B. It's very weird and confusing that a SEE ALL button redirects you to a tab. It doesn't show the user that there is a lot of change in the app status. You want to make it clear to your users that they are in a different place now. Which is why the bar on Option B is very good. You should order all those purchases by date and maybe even show the date on the right side. That way, those who search for ALL PURCHASES will find what they want and as well those who believe they are going to find ALL RECENT PURCHASES will too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that B is the best answer to your question, it remembers the Netflix and Airbnb answer for that same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of; 
a) Reorder menu to // Overview -- Purchases (rename instead of Sales History) -- Vouchers -- Profile  
 
b) Removed totally "See all button" on Recent purchases 
 
c) Optionally: implemented swipe left / right option for Recent purchases, indicated that with icon

As "Purchases" with all purchases is now visible in main menu, next to Overview, you dont need additional button for "See all", and user should catch it right away.